# Loading MAP data type in hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to store key values array aggregated at two levels. My data looks like below.

**I1    I2  Key Val**

L1  C1  K1  V1

L1  C2  K2  V2

L1  C2  K3  V3

So inorder to store all the values for I2. I have writen query as

select I1,I2,UNION_MAP(MAP(Key,Val)) as new_val group by I1,I2

This works great.

But when I do a second level of aggregation all the data in map just wipes out to I2. The query I have used in provided below.

select I1,UNION_MAP(MAP(I2,new_val )) from
(select I1,I2,UNION_MAP(MAP(Key,Val)) as new_val group by I1,I2) out;

This does not give me correct data.

I am expecting data to be like below

(L1,(C1,(K1,V1)))

(L1,(C2,(K2,V2),(K3,V3))))

Can anbody please helpme understand what is wrong here

Comment: Are you using the `union_map` UDAF from [here](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/facebook-hive-udfs)?

Comment: No I am using hive native UDAF as mentioned in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)